# How can I filter my list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I'm trying to filter a list by showing only items contain characters I wrote in the text box, but this filter does not work. When I write "afg" it should only show "Afghanistan".

Thank you

[image]

```js
var Liste=new CreerListe("Pays")

Liste.Add("Afghanistan");
Liste.Add("Afrique du sud");
Liste.Add("Albanie");
Liste.Add("Chili");
Liste.Add("Finlande");
Liste.Add("France");
Liste.Add("Gabon");
Liste.Add("Gambie");
Liste.Add("Honduras");
Liste.Add("Irlande");
Liste.Add("Islande")
Liste.Add("Italie");
Liste.Add("Japon");
Liste.Add("Jordanie");
Liste.Add("Lettonie");
Liste.Add("Liban");
Liste.Add("Malte");
Liste.Add("Maroc");
Liste.Add("Namibie");

function CreerListe(nom) {
 this.nom=nom;
 this.search="";
 this.nb=0; 
 this.Add=AjouterItem;
 this.Afficher=AfficherListe;
 this.MAJ=MAJListe;
}

function AjouterItem(item) {
 this[this.nb]=item
 this.nb++;
}

function AfficherListe() {
 var Z="<SPAN name="+this.nom+"><div class=\"container\">";
 for (var i=0; i<this.nb; i++) {
  Z+="<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\""+this[i]+"\" />"+this[i]+"<br/>"; 
 }
 Z+="</span></div>"
 document.write(Z);
}

function MAJListe(txt,f) {
 if (txt!=this.search) {
  this.search=txt;
  f.elements[this.nom].options.length=0; 
  for (var i=0; i<this.nb; i++) {
   if ( this[i].substring(0,txt.length).toUpperCase()==txt.toUpperCase() ) {
    var o=new Option(this[i], this[i]);
    f.elements[this.nom].options[f.elements[this.nom].options.length]=o;
   }
  }
  if (f.elements[this.nom].options.length==1) {
   f.elements[this.nom].selectedIndex=0;
  }
 }
}

function ListeCheck() {
 Liste.MAJ(document.forms["monform"].search.value,document.forms["monform"].getElementsByName["input"])
 if (document.layers) {
  setTimeout("ListeCheck()", 1001)
 } else {
  setTimeout("ListeCheck()", 100)
 }
}

function hideshow(which){

    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    if (which.style.display=="none") which.style.display="block";
    else which.style.display="none";
};
```

```css
.container {
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    width:300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
  
.tete {
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="text" class="tete" onclick="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('tete1'))"/>
</div>
<div id="tete1">
<form name="monform">
    <input type="text" class="tete" name="search" /> <br />
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
       Liste.Afficher();
       ListeCheck();
        </script>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Ajouter" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

hideshow(document.getElementById('tete1'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change line `if( this[i].substring(0,txt.length).toUpperCase()==txt.toUpperCase() )` to `if( this[i].toUpperCase().indexOf( txt.toUpperCase() ) >= 0 )`

Comment: Thanx for your reply, but it always doesn't work, I think the problem is in ListeCheck() function.